# Batch Script - How to display output from cURL to the console screen which spawned the batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I've been trying to make a batch script that sends a HTTP POST request using cURL. In the cURL command I have told it to output to stdout (http_code, time_total, url_effective). I have been using "timeout /t 20" inbetween each cURL command and that is all I am seeing when I run the script because cURL is running in another console window (which disappears in a flash).

Here's some source code:

```
@echo off

rem -----------------------------------------------------------
rem SCRIPT TO REBOOT AND CHANGE ENCODE TO H264 FOR ACTI CAMERAS
rem -----------------------------------------------------------

rem SCRIPT NAME: ACTI ROOFTOP CAMERAS (REBOOT)
rem ------------------------------------------

start "" C:\curl\curl -sL -d "?USER=user&PWD=pass&SAVE_REBOOT" -w "\n%{http_code}\t %{time_connect}\t %{url_effective}\n" "http://192.168.0.30:80/cgi-bin/system" -o stdout
timeout /t 20

start "" C:\curl\curl -sL -d "?USER=user&PWD=pass&SAVE_REBOOT" -w "\n%{http_code}\t %{time_connect}\t %{url_effective}\n" "http://192.168.0.31:80/cgi-bin/system" -o stdout
timeout /t 20

start "" C:\curl\curl -sL -d "?USER=user&PWD=pass&SAVE_REBOOT" -w "\n%{http_code}\t %{time_connect}\t %{url_effective}\n" "http://192.168.0.32:80/cgi-bin/system" -o stdout
timeout /t 20
```

So the output I'm trying to get is:

```
200    2.00s    http://192.168.0.30:80/cgi-bin/system

Waiting for 15 seconds ...

200    2.00s    http://192.168.0.31:80/cgi-bin/system

Waiting for 15 seconds ...

200    2.00s    http://192.168.0.32:80/cgi-bin/system
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use `start`'s `/b` flag to not spawn a new window.

Comment: Or omit `start` altogether. `Start` is used for when you want _atypical behaviour_. See `start /?` for an explanation of not using and using `start` to start programs.

Comment: Thanks guys for your info. I'll keep looking into it.